# Sort a multidimentional String-Frequence array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, hash

I have to ask the user a string, and the program should order the string and convert it into an array like this

```
[["Letter", frequence]]
[["a", 4],["b", 3],["c",3]]
```

In case of equals frequencies, order alphabetically.

I have this code

```
puts "Write what you want"
text = gets.chomp
text.downcase!
words = text.split("")
print words
frequencies = Hash.new(0)
words.each do |word|
    frequencies[word] += 1
end
frequencies = frequencies.sort_by {|x,y| y}.reverse!
frequencies = frequencies.sort_by {|x| x[1]}
frequencies.each do |word, freq|
    puts word + " " + freq.to_s 
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
str = 'helloworld'
frequency_hash = str.downcase.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }
# => {"h"=>1, "e"=>1, "l"=>3, "o"=>2, "w"=>1, "r"=>1, "d"=>1}
frequency_hash.sort_by { |k,v| [-v, k] }
# => [["l", 3], ["o", 2], ["d", 1], ["e", 1], ["h", 1], ["r", 1], ["w", 1]]
```

Comment: K, I would have used your solution had you used `group_by`.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "Baboon"

h = str.downcase.each_char.group_by(&:itself)
h.merge(h) { |_,a| a.size }.sort_by { |c,f| [-f, c] }
  #=> [["b", 2], ["o", 2], ["a", 1], ["n", 1]]
```

We start by using [String#downcase](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-downcase):

```
s = str.downcase
  #=> "baboon"
```

Then apply [String#each_char](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-each_char):

```
enum = s.each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "baboon":each_char>
```

We could have used [String#chars](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chars):

```
s.chars
  #=> ["b", "a", "b", "o", "o", "n"]
```

but, given the choice, it's better to use an enumerator to avoid the creation of a temporary array.

The elements of the enumerator can be seen by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> ["b", "a", "b", "o", "o", "n"]
```

but we won't do that. Next, we invoke [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) on the enumerator:

```
h = enum.group_by(&:itself)
  #=> {"b"=>["b", "b"], "a"=>["a"], "o"=>["o", "o"], "n"=>["n"]}
```

The operator `&` first uses [Method#to_proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html#method-i-to_proc) to convert the method [Object#itself](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-itself) (Ruby 2.2+) to a proc, and then it calls the proc.

We then use the form of [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that uses the block:

```
{ |_,a| a.size }
```

to determine the value of every key which is present in both hashes being merged (which here is of course every key):

```
g = h.merge(h) { |_,a| a.size }
  # => {"b"=>2, "a"=>1, "o"=>2, "n"=>1}
```

Lastly, [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) provides the desired ordering:

```
g.sort_by { |c,f| [-f, c] }
  #=> [["b", 2], ["o", 2], ["a", 1], ["n", 1]]
```

Comment: Great explanation. But, this way the keys will not be ordered alphabetically when there is a tie in frequency(which OP mentioned in his question). With your current implementation, input: `helloworld` will produce this output: `[["l", 3], ["o", 2], ["d", 1], ["w", 1], ["r", 1], ["e", 1], ["h", 1]]`. But, it should be: `[["l", 3], ["o", 2], ["d", 1], ["e", 1], ["h", 1], ["r", 1], ["w", 1]]`.

Comment: Thank @KMRakibulIslam. I missed the reference to the secondary sort key. I fixed it, but it's a bit less interesting now.

Answer (score 0):

```
mytext = "This is sample text to count all characters in string"
myhash = mytext.downcase.each_char.with_object({}) { |c,h| (h[c] = h.fetch(c,0) + 1) if c =~ /[a-z]/ }
>  myhash.sort_by{|k,v| v}.reverse
#=> [["t", 7], ["s", 5], ["i", 4], ["a", 4], ["e", 3], ["n", 3], ["r", 3], ["l", 3], ["c", 3], ["h", 2], ["o", 2], ["m", 1], ["u", 1], ["p", 1], ["x", 1], ["g", 1]]
```